# firebase-admin - Auth error:TypeError: URL is not a constructor

Tags: api, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I've got a node API that uses firebase-admin to handle firestore data. This wasn't a problem till a few days ago and now it started happening.

The weird thing is, I only seem to get this on my production server and not on local development environment(even using the same database).

I've tried redeploying, restarting the server, checked database configuration and everything and nothing really worked.

This is one of the more detailed errors:

```
Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: URL is not a constructor
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/root/apps/api/src/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/root/apps/api/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1204:28)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/root/apps/api/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/root/apps/api/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
    at callback (/root/apps/api/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:845:24)
```

And this is my connection file:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import serviceAccount from './fbAdminKey'

admin.initializeApp({
    projectId: '<myProjectId>',
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: '<myDbURL>'
})

const db = admin.firestore()
const messaging = admin.messaging()
const auth = admin.auth()

export default { db, messaging, auth }
```

It should be able to just connect to the database and do the operations, I have an app, a web application and they all work normally, just the node API seems to be acting weirdly.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I can confirm the same thing happening on my side. Are you using node version `6.11.5` locally? That's the version the production server is using and I am able properly run it locally only on higher versions (8.x).
Upvoting, since I have the same error and I'll try to write an answer once I come up with something

Comment: Yes, I'm having that realization as well. I have node 8 locally(working fine) and node 6 on the server. I tried to change the version on the server and got some problems with some binaries... As soon as I can get it to work over there I'll confirm it, but I'm almost sure It has something to do with the node version. Btw, I received today an email from the firebase team, advising me about the deprecation of node 6 on the cloud functions, which kind of confirms the theory as well. So yeah, that's what I can say by now, hopefully we can fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after banging my head around for nearly a week, having other problems and stuff, I could figure it out with the help of everybody here.

**The problem was the node.js version**

I was running node `8.4.0` **locally** and node `6.x.x` on **production**. `(firebase-admin 7.0.0)`

So I updated it on production using `nvm` and than got another problem, related to the `grpc` version. I had a newer version installed and it was requiring an older one.

**Note**

If you are using `PM2`, make sure to update it as well:

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/update-pm2/

After that it started working again and it stuff is back on track.

Answer (score 1):

Not the exact solution because it doesn't solve the problem with Node 6.11.5.

The production server runs by default on Node 6.11.5 and if you wanted to change the runtime version to 8, then refer to this article.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_runtime_options

However, keep in mind that this runtime version is currently in beta, so it might break.

I also noticed, that I was able to get rid of this error that you were facing by installing previous version of `firebase-admin` (`6.2.0` to be specific, as for now - the version `7.x.x` is the latest one).

I'm afraid that one of the newer firebase-admin versions broke this feature in some environments and that's why this issue is not that common.